Update many rows with unique value per row minimizing round trips
I need to update many (read 5000+) records with a different new value per row. I am leaning towards option 2 but wanted to ask to community.
Options

I can just loop though the entries and do them one at a time but that is a round trip per record.
I can generate the below query and use executesql
Something I am not thinking of.

The equivalent query I want is:
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyField='SomeValue1' WHERE MyKey='MyKey1';
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyField='SomeValue2' WHERE MyKey='MyKey2';
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyField='SomeValue3' WHERE MyKey='MyKey3';
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyField='SomeValue4' WHERE MyKey='MyKey4';
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyField='SomeValue5' WHERE MyKey='MyKey5';
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyField='SomeValue6' WHERE MyKey='MyKey6';
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyField='SomeValue7' WHERE MyKey='MyKey7';
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyField='SomeValue8' WHERE MyKey='MyKey8';
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyField='SomeValue9' WHERE MyKey='MyKey9';
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyField='SomeValue10' WHERE MyKey='MyKey10';


5000 rows is pocket change for a database server. If this is a one-time operation, I suggest going with whatever is simplest to code, test it, execute it, and forget it. Don't spend time trying to optimize,

There are several third party extensions which can do that via temporary tables and MERGE operator. Are you interesting in that?

I usually serialize the values to JSON and then use OPENJSON to join the table i'm updating, it's fast and one doesn't have to mess with TVPs or bulk. But since you're working in EF, i think any method you choose will be faster than using EF directly

A trick that I've picked up along the way is to use a table-valued constructor as an ad hoc data source. It goes something like this:
select tgt.MyKey,
   tgt.MyField as [before],
   src.MyField as [after]
from dbo.MyTable as tgt
join (values
   ('MyKey1', 'SomeValue1'),
   ('MyKey2', 'SomeValue2')
) as src(MyKey, MyField)
   on src.MyKey = tgt.MyKey;

Then, once you've validated that the before/after look the way you want, change the select to an update.

You could use a numbers table (you have a numbers table right?) or create one in a CTE like so:
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE (
    MyKey VARCHAR(50),
    MyField VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @MyTable (
MyKey,
MyField
)
VALUES 
('MyKey1','Cool1'),
('MyKey2','Cool2'),
('MyKey3','CoolDude'),
('MyKey25','Cool233'),
('MyKey48','Cool2 4 me'),
('MyKey22','Kool Aid');

SELECT
*
FROM @MyTable
ORDER BY MyKey;

WITH cte1(n) AS (
    SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(0) ) t(n)
), cteNumbers (n) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n10.n) AS n
    FROM cte1 AS n10
    CROSS JOIN cte1 AS n100
    CROSS JOIN cte1 AS n1000
    CROSS JOIN cte1 AS n10000 
    CROSS JOIN cte1 AS n100000 -- Just for testing we will have many days, add more as needed
)
UPDATE @MyTable
    SET MyField = CONCAT('SomeValue' , cteNumbers.n)
FROM cteNumbers
LEFT OUTER JOIN @MyTable  AS MT ON  MT.MyKey = CONCAT('MyKey',cteNumbers.n);

SELECT
*
FROM @MyTable
ORDER BY MyKey;

Results of this:
**MyKey MyField**
MyKey1  SomeValue1
MyKey2  SomeValue2
MyKey22 SomeValue22
MyKey25 SomeValue25
MyKey3  SomeValue3
MyKey48 SomeValue48

Credit Błażej Ciesielski from a comment here: https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Is your use of a numbers table here informed by the literal example values that OP provided? I (perhaps incorrectly) assumed that they had actual values for replacement that weren't sequential like this.

@BenThul using (1), (1), (1)... would (in this case) also return 100000 numbers; I find the sequence easier to manage so that if I use for example SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4) ) t(n) I get 1024 numbers and SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8) ) t(n) I get 32768 numbers in cteNumbers and so on.  Adding another cross join like CROSS JOIN cte1 AS n1000000 with 1-4 I get 4096 numbers or with all 1 through 0 I get 1000000 numbers

@BenThul  But yes, I did use the actual number values IN the update due to the literal example used. Also, note the ORDER has nothing to do with the values since my first set was not ordered nor sequential as inserted.

create a Table Variable (@Table) or Temporary Table (#Table) or Global Temporary table (##Table)
as follows:
declare @middletable table 
(value1 varchar(100), key1 varchar(100));
insert into @middletable
(value1,key1) values
('SomeValue1','MyKey1'),
('SomeValue2','MyKey2'),
('SomeValue3','MyKey3'),
('SomeValue4','MyKey4'),
('SomeValue5','MyKey5'),
('SomeValue6','MyKey6'),
('SomeValue7','MyKey7'),
('SomeValue8','MyKey8'),
('SomeValue9','MyKey9'),
('SomeValue10','MyKey10');

use Update with Join as follows
update  m1
set m1.MyField=m2.value1
from dbo.MyTable m1
join @middletable m2
on m1.MyKey=m2.key1

